# ElasticSearch zero downtime to support type swapping of type data

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I dynamically add a new type (with mapping) or drop/recreate an existing type within an existing Elasticsearch index or is indices totally immutable (which I suspect it is)?

Almost like zero downtime "type" swapping when the content needs to be replenished without the need to re-index. I am aware of the Indexing / Alias method to support zero downtime "Index" swapping.

Please forgive me if I am misunderstanding the fundamentals of ElasticSearch.

If this cannot be done is there a workflow / technique that could work?
thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more details the use case you're willing to support?

Comment: Sure: I have delimited files that need to be searchable in ES through an ES type. These files belong to a certain DB which I would like to locate them in ES under an Index with same name as DB. There are multiple DBs  each with its own collection of delimited files (that represent table data),  What happens is: I process one file at a time , ideally would like to  to update that specific type (aka table/file) when I process this file. Part of the processing would be to drop and replace a type. Hope this throws more light on the situation.